# Change Image in UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle programmatically

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have to use `UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle` (as it works brilliantly with `PFTableViewCell`) and I can add a default image through storyboard where there is an option to add an image. This works fine but I want to update this image myself through code. I have the following code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFTableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! SBGestureTableViewCell!

    if cell == nil {
      cell = SBGestureTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    }

    // update cell image from default image to questionMark 
    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "Question_Mark@2x")
}
```

However, the image does not update and I am still seeing the default image.

Comment: Remove the `@2x` from the image name in your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using png images ( since your image name contains @2x), you are missing .png.

If you are using xcassets, then double check the name in the assets.

Also, check console, if you don't have the image name right, it should output it there.

That's all I can get from your code.

Comment: I added the .png. Didn't work. I also added the image to the assets and tried that way but that didn't work either. Thanks though.

Comment: if you add image through assets you don't need @2x. Have you checked the console?